# OpenNI 2.2 + OpenCV 2.4.6 + VS 2010

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni, kinect-sdk

Can anyone tell me how to compile OpenNI 2.2 with OpenCV 2.4.6 in Visual Studio 2010? Previously I compiled OpenNI 1.5 with OpenCV 2.4.5 with the help of this link:

http://seevisionc.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/compiling-opencv-with-openni-for.html

But now the latest version of OpenNI 2.2 doesn't need Primesense driver. So, the Cmake couldn't find the OpenNI.

Please Reply ASAP.

Comment: does opencv now have support for openni2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It is very simple. OpenNI 2.x is much advanced than the previous versions. You don't need to install primesense sensorkinect driver. You can use OpenNI 2.x along with the Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.x.

Install both 64 and 32-bit OpenNI 2.x if you have Windows 7 x64 otherwise only 32-bit. Configure it with Visual Studio 2010 or 12. You can follow this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACqPsV0R4to

Then configure OpenCV for visual Studio 2010 or 12. You can follow this link:

http://4someonehelp.blogspot.in/2013/04/install-opencv-245-using-visual-studio.html

No need to compile OpenCV and OpenNI together. Currently I am using OpenNI 2.2, Nite 2.0, MSDK 1.7, OpenCV 2.4.6 and VS 2010 on my Win x64.

Thanks